# Use of に in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

> たえ子が入っていったのはジュエリーの有名店である。高級店のたたずまいに怖じ気づきつつ、たえ子**に**続く。

(from the book [おまえじゃなきゃだめなんだ](http://books.bunshun.jp/ud/book/num/9784167902759).)

I understand this sentence as

> The store Taeko entered was a famous jewelry store, and while she was intimidated by the fancy shop, たえ子に続く.

I don't get the last part, whether it means "she went on" or something else because に denotes a place at which something is or a direction towards something, so shouldn't it be たえ子がつづく？

Comment: To add a bit to the existing answer - in a sentence with conjunction つつ used for synchronous action, the (implied) agent must be the same. So the one who was afraid was the speaker.

Comment: @user9771 thank you, is つつ always interchangeable with ながら? and since it's "although I was intimidated, I followed her into the store", can つつalso mean "although" instead of "while"? Why didn't they use つつも?

Comment: I'm not qualified to fully answer your first question, but my textbook claims that "the concessive meaning of a statement made with つつ is more formal and neutral than a statement made with  ながら"

Comment: @lettuce They aren't always interchangeable; for example, I think 我ながら can't be rewritten as \*我つつ, and 読みつつある can't be rewritten as \*読みながらある.  As for your question, I think つつ is more commonly 'while' but can occasionally have the 'although' meaning (Martin 1975 has examples on p.417-8).  As you can see, the difference between つつ and ながら is relatively complicated, so why not ask it as a separate question?

Comment: @lettuce Etymologically つつ meant "continue to" and ながら meant somewhat like "on the other hand". I think this should explain why sometimes they're not interchangeable as snailboat said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be 「たえ[子]{こ}**に**[続]{つづ}く」 and not 「たえ子**が**続く」.

「たえ子**に**続く。」＝「私**は**たえ子**に**続く。」

It means "I followed Taeko (into the store)."

「たえ子**が**続く」 makes no sense because Taeko has already entered the store.  Taeko cannot follow Taeko.